# DataTorrent - Developing Hello World Application

Tags: maven, hadoop, curl, bigdata

I am totally new to DataTorrent. I am trying to build a sample application using data torrent using [this](https://www.datatorrent.com/docs/guides/ApplicationPackages.html) link but information given on this page is not much helpfull. I created a maven project as described on page using below command.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeRepository=https://www.datatorrent.com/maven/content/repositories/releases -DarchetypeGroupId=com.datatorrent -DarchetypeArtifactId=apex-app-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=3.0.0 -DgroupId=com.td.example -Dpackage=com.td.example.shashi -DartifactId=shashi-app -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Project was created successfully but after that it says to create a zip file for uploading on application server.

I ran below command to upload it but it is giving problem accessing server.

```
 curl -XPOST -T shashi-app.zip http://hostname:9090/ws/v2/appPackages
```

Any pointer on above issue?

Comment: When I clicked on this link, I was redirected to "403 Forbidden" Page.

Answer (score 0):

The application can be submitted via gateway using REST calls.

- To do that, the apa file needs to be uploaded into the appPackages - you can do this from DT UI console or by using a REST call to POST the jar.

Please check for your syntax of the job submission. The following link has the documentation on uploading the job and submission using REST calls.

http://docs.datatorrent.com/configuration_packages/#post-wsv2apppackagesuserapp-pkg-nameapp-pkg-versionapplicationsapp-namelaunchconfigpackageuserconfpkgname